# How can i dynamically change the UISwitch of UITableView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, delegates, uiswitch

I have a `UItableView` where every `UITableViewCell` is containing a `UISwitch` .Now my question is when i will click in one switch then how can i `OFF` other switches of the `UITableViewCell`

In my code i have already made the view and i can `ON/OFF` the switches.But i want to `OFF` all other switches except my selected switch.

Please some help me by giving an example or source code example.

With Best Regards

**Edit**

My Code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        switchview = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        cell.accessoryView = switchview;
        switchCondition = NO;
        [switchview setOn:NO animated:YES];
        [switchview addTarget:self action:@selector(updateSwitchAtIndexPath:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [switchview release];
    }
    if(switchCondition == YES){
    [switchview setOn:YES animated:YES];
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[cellValueArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}

- (void)updateSwitchAtIndexPath:(UISwitch*)sender {
    if(sender.on){
        switchCondition = YES;
        [table reloadData];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your data model used by the table's data source, then reload the table (or at least the visible rows). This will cause each row to reload and each switch will get updated with the latest data.

Edit: Here's an updated version of your code:

You need an instance variable to track the state of each switch. Create an array to hold the YES and NO values. In the code below I will assume there is an instance variable named `switchConditions` of type `NSMutableArray` that has been setup with `NSNumber` objects representing the YES and NO values for each row. This is similar to your `cellValueArray`. You should also get rid of your `switchView` and `switchCondition` instance variables.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        UISwitchView *switch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        cell.accessoryView = switch;
        [switchview addTarget:self action:@selector(updateSwitchAtIndexPath:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [switch release];
    }

    UISwitchView *switch = (UISwitchView *)cell.accessoryView;
    switch.tag = indexPath.row; // This only works if you can't insert or delete rows without a call to reloadData
    BOOL switchState = [switchConditions[indexPath.row] boolValue];
    switch.on = switchState; // this shouldn't be animated

    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValueArray[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (void)updateSwitchAtIndexPath:(UISwitch*)switch {
    NSInteger row = switch.tag;
    if (switch.on){
        // This switch is on, turn all of the rest off
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < switchConditions.count; i++) {
            switchConditions[i] = @NO;
        }
        switchConditions[row] = @YES;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    } else {
        switchConditions[row] = @YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for quick answer. please give me an example because i can not understand how can i do that..

Comment: Show your code (update your question) for your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` showing how you setup the switch for each row. Also show the code you have for handling the event when a switch's value changes.

Comment: I have question.Now please check what i have to do.

Comment: That code is all wrong. You are using a single ivar for the switch and another to maintain the state. You need to keep track of the state of the switch for every row. Give me a bit and I'll update my answer with some updated code.